# Javascript UIslider result.JS

Tags: javascript, slider, nouislider

I have a problem with my js code:

```
var stepSlider = document.getElementById('slider-step');

noUiSlider.create(stepSlider, {
    start: [ 0 ],
    step: 10,
    range: {
        'min': [  0 ],
        'max': [ 100 ]
    }
});
var stepSliderValueElement = document.getElementById('slider-step-value');

stepSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    stepSliderValueElement.innerHTML = values[handle];
    q1=stepSlider.noUiSlider.get()
});
console.log(q1)
console.log(stepSliderValueElement.innerHTML)
```

It just shows the Start point 0.00, but when I move the value to the 50% it wont change to show me 50. 
EDIT :
i found what is my problem. it's because the slider will update but q1+20 outside of that wont change. but i really need 2 sliders and plot them in a circle percentage way. i can't put those in update way in my code. any idea?
Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Comment: it seems to be changing fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be changing as it should. I put a log on your update method and it's changing the value as it should.

```
stepSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    stepSliderValueElement.innerHTML = values[handle];
    q1=stepSlider.noUiSlider.get()
    console.log(q1);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/0rohoeLg/312/

Comment: first of all thanks for answer.
but i want to keep the result and use it later and for that i need to test console.log(q1) at the last part of the code. and still it does not get the new value for q1.

Comment: I'm not understand because q1 is changing.  It will should you a change if you do a console.log(q1); inside your update method.

Comment: i want that result to be multiplied by another result from another slider but when outside of the function i print it (just to check if it changes and i can use it) it wont give me the good result.
for example outside of the update code console.log(q1+20). i found what is my problem. it's because the slider will update but q1+20 outside of that wont change. but i really need 2 sliders and plot them in a circle percentage way. i can't put those in update way in my code. any idea?